# Nativescript-vue display an image on tap event

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

very new to Nativescript and Vue so please excuse my half baked question.

I am trying to build a small app in which i have an image tag and a button, on press of a button, the image should display, i would like this image source to be passed on as a variable, but on pressing the button, my app crashes, i am writing this in nativescript playground.

here is the code:

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="home-panel">

                <Image src="{{img_src}}" @tap="onImgTap" />
                <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
     const imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
     const imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
     const fileSystemModule = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");
    export default {

    methods: {
        onButtonTap() {
            console.log("Button was pressed");
             img_src:native_img
        },
        onImgTap(){
            alert("Dont press image !");

        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            native_img:"https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png"
        };
    },

}

</script>

<style scoped>
    .home-panel {
        vertical-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        margin: 15;
    }

    .description-label {
        margin-bottom: 15;
    }
</style>
```

really appreciate any help.!

Regards,
~Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is crashing as your to assign value to variable `img_src:native_img` is incorrect.
It should be,

```
onButtonTap() {
   console.log("Button was pressed");
   this.img_src=native_img;
}
```

Also in data need to define `img_src:""`

```
data() {
return {
 native_img:"https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png",
 img_src:""
     };
}
```

Also in Html, src={{img_src}} to :src=img_src

```
<Image :src="img_src" @tap="onImgTap" />
```

Comment: thanks alot for your response,once i made the change it proped the error that native_img is not defined, so i made the following modification this.img_src=this.native_img but still i get the following error                                                         
   Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: {{img_src}}

Comment: Change the syntax img={{src)}} to `:img=src`.. updated answer

Comment: I made the changes but the image wont show up, it has stopped showing the error and my button press is registered but the image would not pop up. here is the url for my project, i am not sure if you can look at it online      https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=11ouHV&v=2       again, thanks alot for your help

Comment: haha this live preview app is cool, I tested on it actually `img_src` was not defined in the `data()` where `native_img` is defined. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=11ouHV&v=4